# filter time periods in redshift

Tags: sql, datetime, amazon-redshift

how to filter time period from `datetime` column in sql. 
have a table with `product, date time and quantity`. 
date time from `00 hrs to 24 hrs` , but requirement is to filter give time range eg from `08:05 to 14:25` , Please suggest

Comment: "date time from 00 hrs to 24 hrs" does not make sense, please can you update your question with a few example rows of data, expected results and what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

if this is a sort key, then first you need to filter the date range and then the time range to ensure you get the benefit of the sort key, e.g.

`WHERE purchase_time > '2017-10-01' AND DATE_PART('hour', purchase_time) BETWEEN 8 and 9`

If you need to be more granular you could do something like:

`WHERE purchase_time > '2017-10-01' AND (DATE_PART('hour', purchase_time) * 100 + DATE_PART('minute', purchase_time)) BETWEEN 805 and 1425`

Comment: why *100 not *60?

Comment: You could use 60 but I find 100 easier. If you use 100 then 14:25 is 1425. If you use 60 then 14:25 is 915 so it's just easier to make mistakes :-)

Comment: thanks for response , WHERE purchase_time > '2017-10-01' AND DATE_PART('hour', purchase_time) BETWEEN 8 and 9 this is dynamic for one day , for multiple dates

Comment: @Tom that's smart! :)